# How to make the colours change in my traffic light sequence

Tags: javascript, html

In this code, the first red traffic light shows up, but it won't change when I click the button. Yes, I know there are similar questions like this one, but they don't seem to help. So if you could tell me what's wrong I would really appreciate it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Task 3</h1>

<p>This is my Traffic Light script</p>

<img id = "light" src="Red Traffic light.jpg">

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>

<script>
var list = [
    "Red Traffic light.jpg",
    "Red & Yellow Traffic light.jpg",
    "Green Traffic light.jpg",
    "Yellow Traffic light.jpg"
];

var index = 0;

function changeLights() {

    index = index + !
    if (index == list.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
}

var image = document.getElementById("light");
image.src=list[index];

</script>
```

Comment: First problem I see is you haven't closed the `changeLights()` function, missing `}` You can add to index using `index++`

Comment: What happens when you add `!` to the `index`?

Comment: hit `ctrl shift i` or right click and inspect element then click the console tab to view errors.

Comment: @AnthonyOr `CTRL`, `Shift` and `J` that will open the console ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added comments into my answer to show the changes.

1. You haven't closed the `changeLights()` function.
2. `index+!` appears to be a typo, use `index++` to add 1.
3. Changes to your if statement as it's missing the last image.

```js
var list = [
    "http://imgur.com/FHT9OoG.jpg",
    "http://imgur.com/XZ1PxGh.jpg",
    "http://imgur.com/5DUX0Wy.jpg",
    "http://imgur.com/WpeEMZU.jpg"
];
var index = 0;
function changeLights() {
index++ // Add 1 to index.
// If index is more than the array length, reset to 0
// Or you can use: if(index == list.length){
if (index > list.length-1){
index = 0;
}
var image = document.getElementById("light");
image.src=list[index];
}
```

```html
<img id = "light" src="http://imgur.com/FHT9OoG.jpg">
<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>
```

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: @bob Very welcome, I hope everything is clear and you understand the changes. If not please just ask and I will be more than happy to explain anything you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to increment index by 1 within `changeLights()`? Looks like you're adding a `!` to index instead, turning it into a string.

Additionally you're not closing the `changeLights()` function (you've closed the `if` conditional only).

Check your console to see if there's an error message when you click the button.

Comment: It won't be a string, it is an error. as ! is not quoted.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger in firefox gives these errors:

`SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'if' lights.html:27:4` a bit cryptic, so we look at what precedes it and see that we have typed `!` instead of `1`, so we fix it, and try again.

`SyntaxError: missing } after function body lights.html:32:25` so we fix it, and try again.