# JavaScript Code: Traffic lights

Tags: javascript

I can't my traffic light code to work. It says line 30 has a syntax problem and I don't know how to fix it. I also need to make the same code but when I press the "Change Lights" button each time i press it a different colour image from the traffic light should appear. However, when I try to change the lights by pressing the button, the traffic light stays on red and will not change to amber.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Traffic Light</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights"()>Change Lights </button>

<script>

var traffic_light = new Array (3)

function lights(){
traffic_light = new Image(300,150)
traffic_light.src = "traffic_light_red.jpg";
traffic_light = new Image(300,150)
traffic_light.src = "traffic_light_redAmb.jpg";
traffic_light = new Image(300,150)
traffic_light.src = "traffic_light_green.jpg";
traffic_light = new Image (300,150)
traffic_light.src = "traffic_light_amber.jpg";
}

function change() {
    traffic_lights++

var traffic_lights = 0
number == number +1
        }
    document.traffic_light_images.src = traffic_light[traffic_lights].src
}
</script>

<img src = "traffic_light_red.jpg" name "traffic_light_images" height = "300" width = "150">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an extra closing curly brace `}`

Comment: Question looks pretty much the same as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364702/how-to-make-the-colours-change-in-my-traffic-light-sequence/36365114#36365114

Answer (score 1):

I see some things (I didn't try to execute your code) :

- First many missings commas :

exemple :

```
var traffic_light = new Array (3)
```

- Then not especially a syntax error but this line :

  number == number +1 //and comma missing

It is a comparaison and you might want to increment, but I don't know your purpose

- The function changeLights() is not defined in your sample.